# How can I set VS Code to generate C# methods in alphabetical order?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't want vscode to generate methods alphabetical order. I want it to order as my click order. There is an option for this in visual studio. But I didn't find a solution for vs code.

Example code:

When i generate first method with clicking [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftEHo.png)

and after i generate second method it shows like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDVv8.png)

So i want vs code to generate code like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hiUQ.png)

I changed "Dotnet > Implement Type: Insertion Behavior" under "Settings > Extensions > C# > Text Editor" to atTheEnd. But it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no option that will enable that.

Comment: That's very bad news. Thanks anyway.